# Is it safe to keep laptop upside down?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hardware-failure, cooling

The air intake of my laptop is on the bottom surface.
Whenever I set some huge files for downloading, I close the lid and keep the laptop upside down.

I am concerned about the HDD getting damaged.

I have searched on some forums, but its a mixed response.
So I would like to have expert opinion.

Comment: using a laptop cooler fan is the correct solution to the problem. I cannot comment on closing of the lid and turning it upside down

Comment: I do not have a heating problem. I just want to know if keeping it upside down will not damage the HDD.

Comment: To quote you "_This causes proper cooling of the laptop_". So when cooling is the intent just use a laptop fan. Ignore my comment if it is irrelevant

Comment: So long as you keep movement (well, acceleration) to a minimum...

Answer (score 3):

There is no concern about the HDD position as long as it's not moved when the laptop is on or the HDD is writing.

Note that laptop manufacturers often put the HDD upside-down.